# Does any Reference Bible include Apocrypha cross references?

Tags: resource-request

I suppose that no popular version (ESV, NKJV, NIV) contain cross references that includes Apocrypha references,especially the ESV thinline reference bible?

ESV is the most popular along with NKJV by Thomas Nelson for x-ref. Does any of its edition included Apocrypha x-ref? The *NRSV reference bible with Apocrypha* must contain them, but I need to find out about the popular version reference bibles.

Comment: Why would you suppose that? There are many largely accepted allusions to the apocrypha in the NT. If Paul even quotes Pagan philosophers we should definitely expect the NT authors to reference Jewish sources!

Comment: I need to confirm this from those who have the ESV reference bibles, or NKJV reference bible.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't like either of those translations, nor do I use study Bibles, so I can't help, but someone else will be able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the New American Bible: Revised Edition. I have [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062084739), which contains extensive cross-references, including to the apocrypha. For example, Romans 12:15 "Rejoice with those who rejoice, weep with those who weep," is cross-referenced to Psalm 35:13, Sirach 7:34, and 1st Corinthians 12:26. It also has many helpful notes and good introductions to each book and subdivision of the Bible.

Comment: Thanks. It's a great study bible. How do you compare it with ESV Diadem with Apocrypha, coz it contains all Apocrypha with ref, not just catholic.

Comment: How is this different from Catholic Study bible?

Comment: It is basically a Catholic Study Bible, but the notes aren't near as thorough or extensive as I usually expect from study bibles.

Comment: Thanks, it is really an amazing and highly scholarly Bible. It maybe considered a study bible which does not focus on systematic theology and apologetics, but on very high scholarly views. I am impressed by its format, and also the NT first communion version. Such a unique format.